# Add column values in a dataframe to values in another dataframe with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe `df`:

```
     test_num  el_num  file_num  value   fail
429         4      1         0   3.36  False
430         4      1         1   3.29  False
431         4      1         2   3.29  False
432         4      1         3   3.26  False
433         4      1         4   3.28  False
434         4      1         5   3.26  False
435         4      1         6   3.27  False
436         4      1         7   3.26  False
437         4      1         8   3.26  False
438         4      1         9   3.18  False
439         4      1        10   3.24  False
440         4      1        11   3.27  False
441         4      1        12   3.32  False
429         5      2         0   3.36  False
430         5      2         1   3.29  False
431         5      2         2   3.29  False
432         5      2         3   3.26  False
433         5      2         4   3.28  False
434         5      2         5   3.26  False
435         5      2         6   3.27  False
436         5      2         7   3.26  False
437         5      2         8   3.26  False
438         5      2         9   3.18  False
439         5      2        10   3.24  False
440         5      2        11   3.27  False
441         5      2        12   3.32  False
```

and a dataframe `diff`:

```
     value  el_num  test_num
198   0.43       1         5
204   0.43       2         5
210   0.46       3         5
216   0.42       4         5
222   0.41       5         5
228   0.43       6         5
234   0.46       7         5
240   0.43       8         5
246   0.44       9         5
252   0.41      10         5
258   0.19      11         5
```

How to add `diff.value` to `df.value` and put it to `df.value` with corresponding `test_num` and `el_num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge then add:

```
df = (df.merge(diff, on=['el_num', 'test_num'], how='left')
   .assign(value=lambda x: x.pop('value_x') + x.pop('value_y').fillna(0))
)
```